# UIBarButtonItem customize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

i try to customize the name of back button item. Do you know what is the method that should be in action ?

This is the code:

```
 UIBarButtonItem * backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:??];
backButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"backButtonNavigation", nil);
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a new method called backButtonClicked, and in it, pop the view controller.

Comment: ok, i think you talk about that:[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]. What about if we want to pop to a specific ViewController ?

Comment: thanks, [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] works very well